# How can I place an image in the background between columns in an HTML table?

Tags: html, image

How can I insert an image between two columns in an HTML table?

Here's what I have:

[image]

This is what I want:

[image]

"want more + arrow" is an image. How can I insert it between the two columns while still maintaining the fixed column widths in the table?

Here's the code:

```
<table style="width:100%;table-layout:fixed;">
  <tr>
    <th><div class="button style3 step">Step 1</div></th>
    <th><div class="button style3 step">Step 2</div></th>
    <th><div class="button style3 step">Step 3</div></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
        <ul>
            <li>Some</li>
            <li>Text</li>
            <li>Here</li>
        </ul>
    </td>
    <td>
        <ul>
            <li>Some</li>
            <li>Other</li>
            <li>Text</li>
            <li>Here</li>
        </ul>
    </td>
    <td>
        <ul>
            <li>Some</li>
            <li>Here</li>
            <li>As</li>
            <li>Well</li>
        </ul>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

It's a table with three columns and two rows.

I'm thinking the solution is to add the image after the **Step 2** table header, something like this:

```
<th><div class="button style3 step">Step 2</div><img src="image.png"></img></th>
```

But it doesn't work, I don't know how I can push the image to the right, even if it spans over the next column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with absolute positioning.

```
.table {
   width:100%;
   table-layout:fixed;
   position:relative;
}
.div {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  right:100px;
}

<table class="table">
  <div class="div"><img src="image.png"></div>
</table>
```

You only need to change the `right:` property in order to position it correctly. The good thing about absolute positioning in this case, is that it doesn't interrupt the flow of your table.

Comment: Why did we have to use `position:relative` on the table?

Comment: You do that because the position of the image `div` is relative to the position of the `table`.

Answer (score 3):

You can position your image.

```
img.mine {
     position: fixed;
     right: 100px;
     top: 0px;
     z-index: 1;
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

huhm, u can try this, give table tag relative attr then give want more + absolute pos att

jsfiddle.net/s085wLdL/